# Validation code produces error InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: python, excel, object, model

I want to add validation code to a cell in an Excel workbook using Python and the Excel Object Model library. My code is as:

```
valid = config.optionsSheet.Range('A2').Validation
valid.Delete()
valid.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, \
    XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, "=R20C4:R21C4", None)
```

The last line above fails with the following error: any help appreciated.

```
EnvironmentError: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Scripting.ComInterop.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object , Object , String , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute6[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , CodeContext , Object , Object , Object , Object , String , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`8.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an exception because of the wrong formula.

I suggest you **manually** create data validation first and correct it until it starts to work properly, I always do it that way. The most common message from Excel when manually typing a wrong formula (in a data validation using lists scenario) is:

> The list source must be a delimited list or a reference to a single row or column.

Take a look at these tutorials, they might help you understand the concept of validation using lists in Excel:

[Apply data validation to cells - office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HP010342173.aspx)

[Excel Data Validation Introduction - contextures.com](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal01.html)